# Fresnel equation with incident angle, n and k as input

Tags: reflection

I've seen a Fresnel equation for calculating the reflection amount at *incidence angle* with *n* and *k* values defined. This formula usually comes up in relation to computer graphics, but I can't find this equation anywhere in a science context.

Here is an example written in Python, taken from this website:
[Fresnel Formula in python](http://therenderblog.com/custom-fresnel-curves-in-maya-part-2/)

Here's the code:

```
def IOR(n,k):
theta_deg = 0

n = n
k = k
fresnel = []
  
while theta_deg <= 90:
theta = math.radians(theta_deg)

a = math.sqrt((math.sqrt((n**2-k**2-(math.sin(theta))**2)**2 + ((4 * n**2) * k**2)) + (n**2 - k**2 - (math.sin(theta))**2))/2)

b = math.sqrt((math.sqrt((n**2-k**2-(math.sin(theta))**2)**2 + ((4 * n**2) * k**2)) - (n**2 - k**2 - (math.sin(theta))**2))/2)
  
Fs = (a**2+b**2-(2 * a * math.cos(theta))+(math.cos(theta))**2)/(a**2+b**2+(2 * a * math.cos(theta))+(math.cos(theta))**2)
Fp = Fs * ((a**2+b**2-(2 * a * math.sin(theta) * math.tan(theta))+(math.sin(theta))**2*(math.tan(theta))**2)/(a**2+b**2+(2 * a * math.sin(theta) * math.tan(theta))+(math.sin(theta))**2*(math.tan(theta))**2))
R = (Fs + Fp)/2
fresnel.append(R)

theta_deg += 1
return fresnel
```

But I can't find any references online for this formula, the Wikipedia article on [Fresnel equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_equations) contains completely different formulas, and I can't see the connection between them. I've searched high and low, but can't find any reference to this particular formula, why is that? Can you help me find it, or explain to me why I can't find it online?

Yes, I realize that I've already have the formula right there in the code sample. But I'm baffled over why I can't find this formula anywhere, I would like to have more sources to cite then just this code example.

Comment: Maybe it is related to the ratio of the poynting vectors with continuous derivatives of the electric and magnetic fields at the interface with different $\mu$ and $\epsilon$ in the mediums? Maybe the n and k comes from a fourier transform of that? I don't remember if that was the derivation of snell or fresnel though.

Comment: What is $\mathrm k$?

Comment: @Mostafa n = index of refraction, k = extinction coefficient. [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Refractive_index#Complex_refractive_index)

Comment: Then they should be the Fresnel equations for reflection from a lossy medium (which are not discussed in that Wikipedia article you linked to).